# Create data frame that is mean average of other data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to take multiple data frames, and merge them to produce a single data frame containing the mean average values of each row of the input data frames. There is one column which is common to each data frame, which can act as an anchor.

Here's a MWE of the problem, using two input data frames as an example:

```
frame_a <- data.frame(column_a = c(1,3,5,7), column_b = c(6,3,4,1))
frame_b <- data.frame(column_a  = c(1,3,5,7), column_b  = c(2,4,6,1))
```

I'd like to produce a new data frame, `frame_c`, using `column_a` as the anchoring 'common' column. The output should contain the following values:

```
column_a  column_b 
       1       4
       3       3.5
       5       5
       7       1
```

I have tried using `frame_c <- ldply(c(a,b))`, but this doesn't average the values; instead it interdigitates them.

Comment: Because you mentioned several datasets (in the global environment), and the example showed starts with `frame`.  I used `ls(pattern="^frame")` to get those objects.  Using `mget` will get a list of the values stored in that object.  Are you saying that you got `numeric(0)` for the example you showed?

Comment: Apologies, yesterday was a poor implementation on my part. I've accepted your answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern="^frame"))
Reduce(`+`, lst)/length(lst)
#    column_a column_b
#1        1      4.0
#2        3      3.5
#3        5      5.0
#4        7      1.0
```

#### Update

If there are `NAs` in other columns, for example

```
frame_a <- data.frame(column_a = c(1,3,5,7), column_b = c(NA,3,4,1))
frame_b <- data.frame(column_a  = c(1,3,5,7), column_b  = c(2,4,NA,1))
lst <- mget(ls(pattern="^frame"))
setNames(as.data.frame(`dim<-`(rowMeans(do.call(cbind,lapply(lst,
          c, recursive=TRUE)), na.rm=TRUE), dim(lst[[1]]))), colnames(lst[[1]]))
#   column_a column_b
#1        1      2.0
#2        3      3.5
#3        5      4.0
#4        7      1.0
```

Or

```
library(abind)
as.data.frame(apply(abind(lst, along=3), c(1,2), mean, na.rm=TRUE))
#   column_a column_b
#1        1      2.0
#2        3      3.5
#3        5      4.0
#4        7      1.0
```

Comment: This works. I wonder if there's some way of ignoring NA values with this? It seems that if any of my dataframes contain a NA, the mean value is calculated as NA as well. I can't seem to add a `na.rm=TRUE` argument to the `Reduce()` function...

Comment: @CaptainProg No problem.  Let me try to create a dataset and test.

Comment: @CaptainProg Would you have `NAs` in the first column ie the column to remain fixed.

Comment: No - only in the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

frame_a %>% 
  left_join(frame_b, by="column_a") %>%              # Merge the two data frames
  rename(col_b1=column_b.x, col_b2=column_b.y) %>%   # Shorten column names
  rowwise() %>%                                      # Do the following row-wise
  mutate(mean_b=mean(c(col_b1,col_b2))) %>%          # Calculate mean of "b" columns 
  select(column_a, mean_b)                           # Keep only the columns we want

  column_a mean_b
1        1    4.0
2        3    3.5
3        5    5.0
4        7    1.0
```